# Material Design: Angular 5. Stepper issue

Tags: angular, tabs, angular-material

I've got an Angular 5 app where I have the `MatTab` control that contains 4 tabs.
Within each tab, I have a `MatStepper`.  In the first tab, the behavior is as expected.
In subsequent tabs, when you click to view the tab, the stepper appears as if all steps are active, rather than only having the first step expanded for the view.

Has anyone had a similar behavior and possibly have an idea of what is causing this?

Comment: Show us your template and component code.

Comment: There is a problem with tabs and expansion panel, maybe it's the same problem? Check this: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5269 and test Lula's solution.

Answer (score 0):

This bug is being solved i guess although i haven't found any info indicating that it's fixed in new versions of angular (i haven't check 6.x yet). https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10965

Problem is somewhat regarding rendering. So if you display stepper after tab is loaded it works fine. This is my solution for now. 
I simply create selectedTab:number variable in my .ts and then this is my html.

```
<mat-tab-group  (selectChange) = 'selectedTab = $event.index'>
  <mat-tab label="tab 1">
    Content 1
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="tab 2">
      <div *ngIf="selectedTab==1;then step2"></div>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

<ng-template #step2>
  <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="true" #stepper>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>
      step 1
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Next</button>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2</ng-template>
      step 2
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext>Next</button>
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 3</ng-template>
      step 3
      <button mat-raised-button color="accent" matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-vertical-stepper>
</ng-template>
```